# Making dvisvgm and Ghostscript from MacTeX talk to each other

Tags: mac, mactex, ghostscript, dvisvgm

I am trying to use dvisvgm to convert pdf files to svg files. When I call `dvisvgm --pdf test.pdf` (for example), I get the response `ERROR: Ghostscript is required to process PDF files`. Both programs are installed via MacTeX-2020 on macOS Catalina, and both programs are in my path (calling both `dvisvgm` and `gs` in the terminal is successful). I have even tried this on a clean install of macOS Catalina with nothing else but MacTeX-2020 installed, with the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: dvisvgm requires the Ghostscript library not the executable. So you have to ensure that `libgs.dylib.9` (or the like) is accessible by the dynamic linker. Otherwise, you can specify its path using environment variable `LIBGS` or dvisvgm option `--libgs`. There's also some information about it on the [dvisvgm manual page](https://dvisvgm.de/Manpage/#opt-libgs).

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the info. MacTeX doesn't tell me exactly which file is the dynamic library that it installed, but, looking though my files, I think it must be `/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/libgs.dylib.9.50` . But then running `dvisvgm --libgs=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/libgs.dylib.9.50 --pdf test.pdf` gives exactly the same error message as before.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to download the Ghostscript 9.50 installer found near the bottom of the page at <https://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html>. Then install but make sure, at the `Installation Type` step, to Customize and have it install the `Ghostscript Dynamic Library`.

Then do

```
export LIBGS=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/libgs.dylib.9.50
```

before running `dvisvgm --pdf ...` I get it to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have installed the Ghostscript dynamic library and I do have the file `/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/libgs.dylib.9.50` . After Martin's comment above, I ran `dvisvgm --libgs=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/libgs.dylib.9.50 --pdf test.pdf` which produced exactly the same error message. Any chance you could point me a bit further in the right direction?

Comment: Look at the order in my answer. The `libgs` argument goes last. That worked for me

Comment: Running `dvisvgm --pdf test.pdf −−libgs=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/libgs.dylib.9.50` I still get `ERROR: Ghostscript is required to process PDF files`.

Comment: Are you using TeX Live 2020? Assuming so there was an update to dvisvgm today. Try updating and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, the second method doesn't seem to work. However, if you export `LIBGS` as given above before running `dvidvgm -pdf test.pdf` it works fine. (Sigh.. I forgot that the LIBGS shell variable was already defined when I ran the second version.)

Comment: Still nothing (on both computers). After setting `export LIBGS=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/lib/libgs.dylib.9.50` and running `dvisvgm --pdf test.pdf`, I still get the same error message.

Comment: TeX Live isn't showing me an update for dvisvgm yet, but I'll keep an eye on that.

Comment: What macOS version are you using? If Catalina, are you using zsh or bash?

Comment: On one machine (my daily computer), I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.3 with bash. On the other (with the clean install), I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.6 with zsh. (I'm really flummoxed that this is happening on both computers.)

Comment: I just checked again and it seems to work so I'm not sure why you are having continuing problems. You might try `export LIBGS=/usr/local/lib/libgs.dylib` which is less error prone; `/usr/local/lib/libgs.dylib` is a symbolic link to the actual library in the original version that's installed when the actual one is installed. I checked and this ran on my system. I'll think about it some more. PS: I get `dvisvgm 2.9.1` when I run `dvidvgm --version` on my system so you can check if you already have it.

Answer (score 2):

I just heard from Richard Koch: Bruno Voison has tracked this one down in detail. In TeXLive 2023 (so MacTeX 2023 onwards), this will be fixed, so that (presumably) all that will be necessary is to install Ghostscript, and then dvisvgm will "just work".  In the meantime, the above solutions will work.

Another possibility is to do the following:

```
$ sudo bash
Password:[type your password]
# chdir /Library/TeX/texbin
# mv dvisvgm dvisvgm.real
# cat > dvisvgm
#!/bin/sh

LIBGS=/usr/local/lib/libgs.9.dylib
export LIBGS
exec dvisvgm.real "$@"
[ctrl-D]
# chmod 755 dvisvgm
# exit
$
```

(where `[ctrl-D]` means hit the ctrl-D combination, not type the characters literally!).

Comment: Thank you very much, this did it for me, though I had to figure out some tweaking. If you use zsh instead of bash, just start with ```sudo chdir ...```. If ```cat > dvisvgm``` does not go through because of permission denied, instead create the file with nano: ```sudo nano dvisvgm```. In this case, ```[ctrl-O]``` writes out the file you have just typed and ```[ctrl-X]``` closes the editor. Also make sure ```/usr/local/lib/libgs.9.dylib``` exists, I had version 10 instead.