# TeX4ht and Tikz missing Ghostcript

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, ghostscript

I'm trying to use TeX4ht with Tikz and running into problems.  Here's my minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\HCode
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output html file shows a missing graphic image.

I'm using TeXLive 2021 on a Mac, installed with MacTeX, and using TeXShop 5.0.

The command I use is "make4ht myfile.tex" (not including the quotation marks.

The make4ht messaging show the warnings

```
--- warning --- Improper groups in \special{t4ht+}... idv[2]
processing of PostScript specials is disabled (Ghostscript not found)
pre-processing DVI file (format version 2)
processing page 2
  DVI error: stack not empty at end of page
```

I suspect the main issue is "missing Ghostscript" but I have Ghostscript installed.  I can run it from the command line with "gs" or "rungs".  In fact it's installed in two locations, once via homebrew at
`/opt/homebrew/bin/gs`
and once via a bundle with TeXShop at
`/usr/local/bin`
The latter is also linked to via a symbolic link contained in `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

I've tried creating a config file for make4ht that has various combinations of
`\Configure{Ghostscript}{rungs}`
or
`\Configure{Ghostscript}{/opt/homebrew/bin/gs}`
etc., but can't get rid of the Ghostscript not found error.

Any advice?

Comment: I was able to generate the html page correctly. I am using `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3)`  with the package `miktex-ghostscript-bin-64` (MikTeX executable for windows x64) installed.

Comment: Ghostscript is called from `dvisvgm` when you use the TikZ driver for TeX4ht, so `\Configure{Ghostcript}` cannot fix that. It is possible that the driver in your distribution is old, you can try to place the [current version](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht) of the driver to the directory with your document, and try if it fixes this issue. If it fails too, please update your question with the debug log (using `make4ht -m draft -a debug myfile.tex`)

Comment: Thanks for the help. dvisvgm fails to find Ghostscript when I run it from the command line.  I will reinstall Ghostscript and follow the steps here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559640/making-dvisvgm-and-ghostscript-from-mactex-talk-to-each-other and let you know if that works.

Comment: Sure, that seems like a probable reason. I hope reinstall will help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [michal.h21](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21)!

From the command line dvisvgm couldn't find Ghostscript. More precisely it couldn't find the dynamic libraries.  So I followed the steps at [Making dvisvgm and Ghostscript from MacTeX talk to each other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559640/making-dvisvgm-and-ghostscript-from-mactex-talk-to-each-other)

1. Reinstalled Ghostscript, use the customize option to add the libgs dynamic libary
2. export the environment variable for LIBGS
3. Download the latest dvisvgm driver that Michael mentioned in his comment.
   Everything works!